# Deactivate right toggle in one VC using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm Using SWRevealViewController in my project.

Now I have a class where I do not need the right toggle menu, am I able to deactivate it for this class?

The only way I successfully tested was to set the rightViewRevealWith to 0 like that:

```
            revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 0
```

I hope some of you have a better solution for me.